# grunt print variable to template

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am trying to print a variable to a banner template, but the output is an empty comment, is it possible to insert the value to the template?

My code:

```
//get the license text
var license = grunt.file.read('license.txt', {'encoding': 'utf-8'});
```

Then in the uglify task i want to add that text as the banner

```html
uglify: {
    options: {
        compress: true,
        mangle: true,
        sourceMap: false,
        banner: '/*! <%= license %> */'
    },
    target: {
        src: 'dist/app.min.js',
        dest: 'dist/app.min.js'
    }
},
```

But the outputed file contains only an empty comment before any code begins

```
/*!  */
```

I can console.log(license) which confirms its value is retrieved correctly.

Comment: try this : `grunt.config.set('uglify.license', license);` and replace `<%= license %>` by `<%= uglify.license %>`

Comment: Was your grunt file scaffolded with yeoman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it seems that the encoding is causing the issue.

Unaware of your entire grunt setup, the license variable should be placed in a config object, eg:

```
var appConfig = {
  app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
  dist: 'dist',
  license: grunt.file.read('license.txt')
};
```

(notice the utf-8 encoding is removed).

The uglify task I have is slightly different - no use of the `compress`, `mangle`, `sourceMap` options. It also seems that you can use `target` or `my_target`:

```
uglify: {
  options: {
    banner: '/*! ' + '<%= yeoman.license %> */'
  },
  my_target: {
    files: {
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js']
    }
  }
 }
```

This is working. Simplified grunt file:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  ...

  // Configurable paths for the application
  var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist',
    license: grunt.file.read('license.txt')
  };

  grunt.initConfig({

    yeoman: appConfig,

    ...

    uglify: {
      options: {
        banner: '/*! ' +
          '<%= yeoman.license %> */'
      },
      my_target: {
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js']
        }
      }
     },

    ...

  });

};
```